# Application restart is needed or not after patching on database server

Tags: unix, web-applications, rhel, patch

I have installed an application on one server and database on other. Now, I'm planning to patch my DB server(OS).So can anyone tell me if I would need to stop and
start the application during this activity as I'm going to stop my DB during this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

No one can answer for sure without knowing your application. But in most cases you have to stop your application for 2 reasons:

1. It wont accept requests while the DB is down (say you do not want users to submit tickets, place orders, ... while the DB can not save them)
2. You will be sure that your application can **re**connect to the db after its restart.